# soup class selector returns an empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve a list of links from a google search page, but the beautiful soup selector returns an empty list.

I got the page code using `requests` and parsed the retrieved response using bs4 BeautifulSoup, then used the `soup.select` method to get a certain class. I end up getting an empty list

```
import webbrowser as wbb
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

term = "minmax"
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(term))
soup = BS(res.text)
links= soup.select(".rc")
```

I expect a list `links` that contain the `rc` class, but get an empty list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `user-agent` header. Google seems to reject requests without one.

This works:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

term = "minmax"
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(term), 
                   headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select(".rc")
print(links)
```

Comment: OP uses exactly the same selector as you do. What did the trick is specifying an user-agent. Please update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no tag with class="rc" in the HTML that the requests get. You can add the following code snippets to confirm the HTML source to confirm.

```
with open("google.html", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(soup.prettify())
```

That will create google.html. Just open it by any text editor and you won't find any tag with class="rc". You probably find out a tag with class="rc" in a DevTools in Google Chrome or some equivalent in other browsers.

Why there are tags with class="rc" when you view HTML in DevTools and there are no tags in the HTML requests get? That's because the HTML the requests get is the **original** HTML that Google Http server response, where the HTML you view in DevTools show the HTML **after** JavaScript DOM modify the HTML.

Because there is no JavaScript will be executed automatically when you get HTML via requests, you have to build CSS selector according to the original HTML(The HTML before JavaScript DOM modify the HTML). If you don't want to write python code to get original HTML every time, you also can view the original HTML in Google Chrome. Just view the web page you want, then right-click and select "View Page Source". It will show the original HTML which is **before** JavaScript DOM change the HTML content.

It seems the links start with the following code.

```
<a href="/url?q=
```

So you can change the CSS selector something like this.

```
links= soup.select('a[href^="/url?q="]')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified thus Google blocks a request and you received a completely different HTML with different selectors since the default requests `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands it and block the request. Learn more about [request `headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Pass `user-agent` into [request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

You can use `f`-string instead of `.format()`:

```py
term = "minmax"
res = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={term}')
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "fus ro dah"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(f"{title}\n{link}\n")

------
'''
Unrelenting Force (Skyrim) | Elder Scrolls | Fandom
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)

Fus Ro Dah | Know Your Meme
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah

Skyrim:Unrelenting Force - The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force

Fus ro dah - Urban Dictionary
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah

Fus Ro Dah GIFs | Tenor
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs

Fus Ro Dah | Etsy
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah

Super Fus Ro Dah - Skyrim Special Edition - Nexus Mods
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/4889/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out why `CSS` selector isn't working or you received a completely different HTML result since extraction and bypass blocks from search engines are already done for the end-user. The only thing that really needs to be done is to iterate over JSON string and get what you need.

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "fus ro dah",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(f"{result['title']}\n{result['link']}\n")

--------
'''
Unrelenting Force (Skyrim) | Elder Scrolls | Fandom
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)

Fus Ro Dah | Know Your Meme
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah

Skyrim:Unrelenting Force - The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force

Fus ro dah - Urban Dictionary
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah

Fus Ro Dah GIFs | Tenor
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs

Fus Ro Dah | Etsy
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah

Super Fus Ro Dah - Skyrim Special Edition - Nexus Mods
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/4889/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.